# Expect one of several versions of content

Tags: rspec, capybara

Two newbs are working on our first little ruby/sinatra gizmo, a cat fighting game.

Our caybara test looks like this, but it passes only some times (when content eq 19) - the HP (starting at 20) can be reduced by 1, 2 or 3. How would you solve this?

```
feature 'reduce hp' do
    scenario 'get a confirmation with lower HP' do
        sign_in_and_play_and_scratch
    expect(page).to have_content (19 or 18 or 17)
  end
end
```

Many thanks from Sweden

Answer (score 2):

have_content takes a string or a regex to match against, so for multiple potential matches a regex is the easiest

```
expect(page).to have_content(/19|18|17/)
```

Comment: @ChristopherKummelstedt You're welcome - Don't forget to accept the answer (the checkmark) so other people know it has been answered